How to make trigger change work in Select2?
There is a piece of code that is responsible for updating the QR code during events ['paste', 'keyup', 'change'], but for some reason the Select2 list does not work and accordingly, does not transmit data.
my part of code
let apply_reload_qr_code_event_listeners = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-reload-qr-code]').forEach(element => {
            let events = ['paste', 'keyup', 'change'];
            events.forEach(event_type => {
                element.removeEventListener(event_type, reload_qr_code_event_listener);
                element.addEventListener(event_type, reload_qr_code_event_listener);
            })
        });
    }

Even though data-reload-qr-code is added to input Select2, it does not work, but all other fields work without problems.
